# Basic Calculus Question On Trig substitution III

Tags: calculus

$$\int\sqrt{6x-x^2}\mbox{d}x$$
What is the answer to this tricky little problem??

Answer (score 3):

**A start:** Express the thing inside the square root as $9-(x-3)^2$. Then make the substitution $x-3=3\sin\theta$.

**Remark:** We used the conventional completing the square approach, since that *has* to be learned. For this particular type of example, there is a nice shortcut.

Comment: I do that, but I am not sure what to do after that...my brain has gone dead...

Comment: We get $dx=3\cos\theta\,d\theta$. Substitute. Note that $\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}=\sqrt{9-9\sin^2\theta}=3\cos\theta$. So we need to find $\int 9\cos^2\theta\,d\theta$. You probably have already covered this integral. One way is to use the double-angle formula $\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta -1$ to express $\cos^2\theta$ as $\frac{1+\cos 2\theta}{2}$. Now the integration is I hope easy.

Comment: You can also do it by converting the thing inside the square to 9-(x-3)^2 and then applying the equation for integral of root of a^2-x^2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try doing this. Put $x= 6 \cdot \sin^{2}\theta$, then what basicall you have is the following
\begin{align*}
6x-x^{2} &= 36\cdot \bigl(\sin^{2}\theta - \sin^{4}\theta\bigr)
\end{align*}

Taking the square root you have the value as $6 \cdot \sin\theta \cdot \cos\theta$, so basically you want to solve the integral $$\int 3 \cdot \sin 2\theta \ d \theta$$